# how to toggle between words when button is clicked in android

Tags: android

Iam new to android programming. I was trying to toggle between words when a button is clicked but when i try to do so it toggles only ones and not continually if the user clicks the button. Any suggestions would be helpful.

mainactivy code:

```
package com.example.helloworld;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    
    import static com.example.helloworld.R.id.text123;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
        public void ONCLICK(View view) {
    
            TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(text123);
    
            text2.setText("Hello");
            if (text2.getText().equals("Hello")) {
                text2.setText("Hello!!!");
            } else {
                text2.setText("GoodBye!!");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does the text become "Hello!!!" after first click? What the text is before clicks?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in logic here.

```
text2.setText("Hello");
if (text2.getText().equals("Hello")) {
```

You are setting the text value to "Hello" everytime the button clicks without even getting inside the condition. Which means your value for text is same all the time and it doesn't change.

```
} else {
    text2.setText("GoodBye!!");
}
```

This is the reason why you are not reaching the else statement to change the text value.

To fix this we should move the statement which changes the text value to outside the button click. So that we can allow our logic if-else to change the text value.

For this we can make use of boolean data type, which only returns true or false. So let me show you how we use it.

In your activity we declare a global variable boolean value to false which tracks the value inside the text correctly and it will change only when text changes.

```
private Boolean toggleMyText = false
```

Now let's get reference to our `TextView` and set value to it only once then our logic takes care of changing it's value.

Declare a global text variable, just below the boolean variable like before:

```
private TextView text2;
```

In onCreate():

```
text2 = findViewById(R.id.text123);
text2.setText("Hello");
```

Also remove the import static statement for text id from imports.

```
import static com.example.helloworld.R.id.text123;
```

Now we set click listener to the button.

You have added click listener to button in layout itself with value "onClick".
So let's call it in Acitivity class outside the onCreate()

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    // Add if-else logic here
}
```

Now let's add the if-else logic statement

```
if (toggleMyText == true) {
    text2.setText("Hello!!!");
    toggleMyText = false;
} else {
    text2.setText("GoodBye!!");
    toggleMyText = true;
}
```

In above statements,
If the toggleMyText is true we change value of text. Also we change boolean value to false.

Now the boolean value changes for next click so that the value inside the text will also change.

Comment: do we add the text2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() inside the onCreate function

Comment: Yes! After setText add this, because you need to find it's id before setting click listener to it.

Answer (score 0):

According your code, you set text as "Hello" before condition every time. So, the condition `text2.getText().equals("Hello")` is always `true` and you get "Hello!!!" every time.